# Fans keep running after computer is shut down

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan

All the fans (CPU, system fans, PSU) keep running after I shut down Windows 8. This is also the case when I put the system on sleep or hibernate. Sometimes the fans run at full speed after shutdown and sometimes they run at lower speeds. This has nothing to do with high temperature. All the parts are new and it has been like this since day one. 
The motherboard is a `Gigabyte Z87-HD3`

I have tried disconnecting the power cable, holding the power button (to "empty" the power) and disconnecting/reconnecting the fan cables.

EDIT: Powerled is also on after shutdown/sleep/hibernate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the pins on the CPU socket were bent, this must have happened when installing the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would check for is if there is a newer BIOS available for your motherboard.  If there is then flash that.  Be warned that there is always an element of risk in flashing a new BIOS.

It sounds like an [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) issue.  If a newer BIOS is not available or flashing one doesn't correct the issue then check the manufacturers web-site and see if there are any drivers for your motherboard available.  You should not need to do this, it should just work, but obviously it isn't working.

Edit: BIOS may also be called "firmware" if you have a UEFI motherboard.

Comment: Now the computer won't even boot. It just shows a cursor on the screen then goes "No Signal" then sounds like it's restarting then repeats.

Comment: Did you do anything or did this new behavior start on its own?

Comment: I tried to start windows in safe mode by holding down shift when pressing restart, but I accidently pressed shutdown

Comment: And?  Have you unplugged the computer from the wall and pressed the power button to discharge the capacitors and then replugged it and see if it will POST?

Comment: Yes and windows won't start, the thing with the cursor and no signal keeps repeating

Comment: Did you do anything to cause this?  Did you flash a new firmware or did this behavior start with no reason from yourself?

Comment: Nothing like that, just pressed shift while shutting down windows

Comment: If all the parts are new then RMA them to the manufacturer and get replacements.  The likely parts are the PSU and the mainboard.  Other parts should not affect your system in any power-related way.  You did plug in the PSU connection to the motherboard right, right?  20+4 pin connectors in their proper positions?

Comment: Yes, I mean it wouldn't work at all if it weren't plugged in the proper position, right?

Comment: It's been a while since I built a rig, I remember them being keyed so they couldn't be inserted wrong - but some mainboards just take the 20 and the 4 are optional while other mainboards need the 20+4.

Comment: Anyway, the issue has been like this since you bought it.  I'd RMA and get new parts.